# Adding image objects to wpf with code

Tags: c#, wpf, simulator

I'm a rookie at C# and WPF and I'm trying to create a simple car-simulator. Mainly the idea of the simulator is that I have C#-class that creates car-objects that have for example speed variable that can be changed and timer for moving from left to right. I want to do movement with timer and not for example `doubleanimation`. In WPF I have AddCarButton for adding cars in certain points in Canvas.

The problem is I dont know how to add cars to Canvas. This is very frustrating because it doesn't sound like a big thing to do but I feel like I have tried everything and not succeeded.

This is latest attempt with car-class. I have tried using Canvas.Set-methods but failed.

```
class car
{
    private int speed;

    public car(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
        GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources.car.png"));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        //Canvas.SetBottom(g, 0);
        //Canvas.SetLeft(g, 0);
        //Canvas.SetBottom(bmp, 0);
        //Canvas.SetLeft(bmp, 0);
    }
    public void addCar(car c)
    {
        Canvas.SetBottom(c, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(c, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Your image is in the resources, so why not access it in the regular way with Properties.Resources.<ImageName> rather than using reflection to extract it?

Comment: Please read at least [Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx) before starting to code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're coding on WPF you shouldn't use *Windows Forms* stuff. To work with images you use **BitmapSource** and its derived classes, and to access your resources programmatically you usually use **pack URIs**. It's not the only way, though.

Here is a little example that draws some images on a canvas control.

The XAML code for the canvas could be like this (it's just an example):

```
<Canvas Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" />
```

and your main window code...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BitmapImage carBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/BlueCar.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Image[] carImg = new Image[5];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        double maxX = canvas1.Width - carBitmap.Width;
        double maxY = canvas1.Height - carBitmap.Height;
        for (int i = 0; i < carImg.Length; i++)
        {
            carImg[i] = new Image();
            carImg[i].Source = carBitmap;
            carImg[i].Width = carBitmap.Width;
            carImg[i].Height = carBitmap.Height;
            Canvas.SetLeft(carImg[i], rnd.NextDouble() * maxX);
            Canvas.SetTop(carImg[i], rnd.NextDouble() * maxY);
            canvas1.Children.Add(carImg[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you need change the name of your image resource. By the way, to add an image go to **Project** > **Add existing item...** and select your image file, now your image will appear in the *Solution explorer* (by default, Visual Studio stores image resources in a folder called "Images"), if you select it you'll see in the *Properties* window that its **Build action** is **Resource**, ***don't change this!*** (some people think it should be *Embedded resource* but that's incorrect).

If you don't get this `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/BlueCar.png", UriKind.Absolute)`, you should read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on **pack URIs**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still having problems adding cars to canvas. For command "Canvas.SetLeft(car(..." I get error "cannot convert from 'Simulator.car' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'". How can I make my car-class act like a UIElement or transform it to UIElement so it can be added?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your bitmap in an `Image` (and not `Graphics`), and then you need to add the image to the canvas:

```
Canvas.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: @Sam `Image` here means the [WPF Image control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), and bitmap is not the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you used, but could be a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx).