# Usage of a Picture instead of Rectangle Shape in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes

Background: I am currently busy with showing position of a Vehicle on a Zoomable Canvas based on the Position (X,Y) and Orientation (for Rotation). I use Rectangle for visualizing the vehicle. Everything works well but I got a bit greedy and now I want to replace the Rectangle with Top View Picture of the Vehicle, so it looks that the vehicle itself is moving instead a Rectangle.

Code Below:

```
private void PaintLocationVehicle(VehicleClass vc)
{

    IEnumerable<Rectangle> collection = vc.ZoomableCanvas.Children.OfType<Rectangle>().Where(x => x.Name == _vehicleobjectname);
    List<Rectangle> listE = collection.ToList<Rectangle>();
    for (int e = 0; e < listE.Count; e++)
        vc.ZoomableCanvas.Children.Remove(listE[e]);

    // Assign X and Y Position from Vehicle
    double drawingX = vc.gCurrentX * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
    double drawingY = vc.gCurrentY * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
    // Scale Length and Width of Vehicle
    double tractorWidthScaled = vc.tractorWidth * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
    double tractorLengthScaled = vc.tractorLength * GlobalVar.DrawingQ;
    // Get Drawing Location
    double _locationX = drawingX - (tractorLengthScaled / 2);
    double _locationY = drawingY - ((tractorWidthScaled  / 2));
    RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();
    // Angle in 10th of a Degree
    rotation.Angle = vc.gCurrentTheeta/10 ;
    double i = 0;
    //paint the node
    Rectangle _rectangle = new Rectangle();
    _rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(vc.VehicleColor == "" ? "Black" : vc.VehicleColor));
        _rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(vc.VehicleColor == "" ? "Black" : vc.VehicleColor));
        i += 0;
    _rectangle.Width = tractorLengthScaled ;
    _rectangle.Height = tractorWidthScaled;
    rotation.CenterX = _rectangle.Width / 2;
    rotation.CenterY = _rectangle.Height / 2;
    _rectangle.RenderTransform = rotation;
    Canvas.SetTop(_rectangle, _locationY + i);
    Canvas.SetLeft(_rectangle, _locationX + i);
    _rectangle.SetValue(ZoomableCanvas.ZIndexProperty, 2);
    string _tooltipmsg = "Canvas: " + vc.ZoomableCanvas.Name;
    // Assign ToolTip Values for User
    _tooltipmsg += "\nX: " + vc.gCurrentX;
    _tooltipmsg += "\nY: " + vc.gCurrentY;
    _rectangle.ToolTip = _tooltipmsg;
    _rectangle.Name = _vehicleobjectname;
    //add to the canvas
    vc.ZoomableCanvas.Children.Add(_rectangle);
}
```

Note: `VehicleClass` holds all the Values for a certain Vehicle. `DrawingQ` holds the transformation scale from Reality to Zoomable Canvas.
So the issues I forsee:

1. How to append the Size of a Jpeg file to get the size same as
   Rectangle?
2. What kind of Shape object shall I use? Please
   suggest.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @series0ne I am using WPF and not Forms. Sorry for not mentioning before!

Comment: Look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866758/placing-bitmap-in-canvas-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336597/adding-image-objects-to-wpf-with-code

Comment: Use an appropriate ImageBrush for the Rectangle's Fill property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i undrestand you correctly. you wanted to show an image of the vechicle inside the rectangle. in order to do that you can use

> ImageBrush and assign to the Rectangle Fill property

something like this

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 100;
        rect.Height = 100;
        ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("vehicle image path");
        bmp.EndInit();
        img.ImageSource = bmp;
        rect.Fill = img;
```

I hope that helps